# Two if in a for loop won't work for a FizzBuzz

Tags: python

I have this super simple code of FizzBuzz on Python 3 that must work but it doesn't. The output looks like
FizzBuzz
1
2
3
4
Buzz
6
7
8
9
Buzz
11
12
13
14
FizzBuzz

Works for the 5 and 15 but not for the 3. I know I could solve this in other ways but I would like to know what I am missing in this bite.

```
for i in range(100):
    output="";

    if i % 3 == 0:
        output += "Fizz";
        
    if i % 5 == 0:
        output += "Buzz";
        
    else:
        output = i
        
    print(output)
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: Extra note, in Python, we don't need semicolons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` happens when you hit 3. That is your bug.

This is because the `else` only applies to the second `if`.

Maybe you can try replacing the `else` with `if not output:`.

Answer (score -1):

The `else` is only referring to the second `if` statement. You could change the `else` to be something like:

```py
if not output:
```

which is the same as:

```py
if output == "":
```

This effectively is making sure none of the other two ifs have run.